# Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'nativescript-sound'

Tags: android, nativescript

I am trying to use nativescript-sound package in my nativescript/vue-cli based app.I install nativescript-sound using

> npm install --save nativescript-sound

After installing this i run npm clean and than try to call nativescript-sound on my project's main.js file

```
require("nativescript-vue").registerElement("sound", () => require("nativescript-sound").sound);
```

When i try to run

> npm run watch:android

compiler showing me error.

**Error**

```
 ERROR in ./src/main.js
 Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'nativescript-sound' in 
 '/home/darahat/Desktop/Rhymes/src'
 @ ./src/main.js
```

1. My Question is why it showing error?
2. Is nativescript-sound support nativescript/vue cli?
3. If not support which plugin i can use to add background sound and 
   click button sound?

Comment: Have you tried https://market.nativescript.org/plugins/nativescript-audio?

Comment: @TinusJackson I saw **nativescript-audio** doc.There they said that it provides audio recorder as well as audio player.but i need to play sound background of my app moreover when i tap on button it will beep.would you think nativescript-audio can solve my problem?

Comment: I Believe it would

Answer (score 0):

I changed in
node_modules/nativescript-sound/package.json

```
"main": "sound.js",
```

to

```
"main": "sound",
```

**and it works!**

```
let Sound = require("nativescript-sound");
```